# VMs are not pinging while start the SDN OPENDAYLIGHT Controller

Tags: virtual-machine, mininet, opendaylight, openvswitch, sdn

I am new to the SDN-Openflow and trying to install a labsetup in my PC using VM,i have successfully installed two VM's and able to ping in between them.

In one VM There is ODL,OVS and MININET and in another one there is only OVS.(VM settings are NAT and Host Only Adapter for both)
**i want to create a topology with mininet and attache the mininet with the OVS in one VM and connect that OVS with the another VM OVS and ping h1 and h2 (created by mininet)**

In VM1 BR0 ip 192.168.56.103 and in VM2 BR0 ip 192.168.56.102(which is actually Eth1 IP i mapped with Br0),controller IP is 127.0.0.1.

I set the controller with both the OVS switches(for VM1 127.0.0.1 and for VM2 192.168.56.103)

Upto this everything is OK,but when i start the controller ./run.sh.the VM2 stop pinging but i can able to see the OVS of VM2 in the ODL GUI with a host (192.168.56.XXX)

Please help me on that

Regards
Rupak